# Is a DHCP offer packet a broadcast or unicast?

Tags: protocol-theory, dhcp, udp, broadcast

DHCP OFFER is a layer3 broadcast because the server doesn't know the client's IP, ***but*** the server knows the client's MAC address. So why does it send the OFFER as L2 broadcast?

If anyone ask me about this - how should I answer? Can I say its layer3 broadcast and layer2 unicast?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Be aware of the broadcast flag, see [RFC2131](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt) (page 24):

> A client that cannot receive unicast IP datagrams until its
>   protocol
>       software has been configured with an IP address SHOULD set the
>       BROADCAST bit in the 'flags' field to 1 in any DHCPDISCOVER or
>       DHCPREQUEST messages that client sends.  The BROADCAST bit will
>       provide a hint to the DHCP server and BOOTP relay agent to broadcast
>       any messages to the client on the client's subnet.

**EDIT**

> A client that can receive unicast IP datagrams before its protocol software has been configured SHOULD clear the BROADCAST bit to 0. The BOOTP clarifications document discusses the ramifications of the use of the BROADCAST bit.

Added the rest of the RFC. According to the entire paragraph, it could be ***either broadcast, or unicast or even both***.

Answer (score 14):

The answer is that it can be either broadcast or unicast - and in some cases both unicast and broadcast before it reaches the client when an `ip helper-address` is used.

A client doesn't actually have an IP address until the DISCOVER-OFFER-REQUEST-ACK exchange is completed.  It is possible (although *very* unlikely) to have a situation arise where the server will resond to the REQUEST with a NAK.

However, since unicast is generally preferred over broadcast, many clients will accept a unicast reply that matches their L2 address.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt

As per this RFC:

Droms                       Standards Track                    [Page 24]

RFC 2131          Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol         March 1997

Normally, DHCP servers and BOOTP relay agents attempt to deliver
   DHCPOFFER, DHCPACK and DHCPNAK messages directly to the client using
   uicast delivery.  The IP destination address (in the IP header) is
   set to the DHCP 'yiaddr' address and the link-layer destination
   address is set to the DHCP 'chaddr' address.  Unfortunately, some
   client implementations are unable to receive such unicast IP
   datagrams until the implementation has been configured with a valid
   IP address (leading to a deadlock in which the client's IP address
   cannot be delivered until the client has been configured with an IP
   address).

A client that cannot receive unicast IP datagrams until its protocol
   software has been configured with an IP address SHOULD set the
   BROADCAST bit in the 'flags' field to 1 in any DHCPDISCOVER or
   DHCPREQUEST messages that client sends.  The BROADCAST bit will
   provide a hint to the DHCP server and BOOTP relay agent to broadcast
   any messages to the client on the client's subnet.  A client that can
   receive unicast IP datagrams before its protocol software has been
   configured SHOULD clear the BROADCAST bit to 0.  The BOOTP
   clarifications document discusses the ramifications of the use of the
   BROADCAST bit [21].

A server or relay agent sending or relaying a DHCP message directly
   to a DHCP client (i.e., not to a relay agent specified in the
   'giaddr' field) SHOULD examine the BROADCAST bit in the 'flags'
   field.  If this bit is set to 1, the DHCP message SHOULD be sent as
   an IP broadcast using an IP broadcast address (preferably 0xffffffff)
   as the IP destination address and the link-layer broadcast address as
   the link-layer destination address.  If the BROADCAST bit is cleared
   to 0, the message SHOULD be sent as an IP unicast to the IP address
   specified in the 'yiaddr' field and the link-layer address specified
   in the 'chaddr' field.  If unicasting is not possible, the message
   MAY be sent as an IP broadcast using an IP broadcast address
   (preferably 0xffffffff) as the IP destination address and the link-
   layer broadcast address as the link-layer destination address.

Answer (score 3):

A DHCP server is answering with a DHCP OFFER to provide an IP address.
It knows the target MAC and IP, hence will use a unicast IP packet, toward the
originating Ethernet address, hence a unicast Ethernet frame too.

If you want to see it for real, just enter the following command on your DHCP server:

`tcpdump -i`*my_ethernet_device*`-e src port bootps`

where *my_ethernet_device* is the name of the Ethernet interface on which your DHCP server is replying to your network.

Comment: could you please tell me about ack,request packets also whether they are unicast or broadcast?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780760%28v=ws.10%29.aspx in this link they are saying that the offer packet is broadcast

Comment: Run a `tcpdump` (or a `wireshark`) and conclude for yourself how it is really working.

Comment: i haven't any of them in my system please conclude here.

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say that DHCP Server _knows_ the target IP address. It may know what ip address the host may want, it may know what ip address that itself offers, but the ip address isn't yet agreed upon. Otherwise what's the point of these exchanges anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The DHCP server may be present outside your network and thus we need to broadcast on Network layer as well.

The server responds with either a broadcast or a unicast message using UDP
source port number 67 and destination port number 68. The response can be unicast because the server knows the IP address of the client. It also knows the physical address of the client, which means it does not need the services of ARP for
logical to physical address mapping. However, some systems do not allow the
bypassing of ARP, resulting in the use of the broadcast address.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop or laptop or server or any other endpoint connecting to network through wireless or wired  intiàtes DHCP discover message to DHCP server  within data segment layer in osi model with destination  Mac address as  FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF

Frame with this DISCOVER message after reaches the DHCP Server .

After the DHCP Server gets  discover message from client DHCP server responds suggesting the IP address available offering to the client host by unicast message frame as source address as DHCP server Mac address and destination address as clients Mac address .

Note : DHCP server knows client Mac address from DHCP client discover message
This offer message contains .

proposed IP address for client for example 172.16.2.16
subnet mask to identify the subnet space for example 255.255.255.0
IP of default gateway for subnet for example 172.16.2.1
Internal dns server ip address if hosted, other wise external dns address will be used as configured on DHCP pool .

So finally we can conclude DHCP offer message is unicast from DHCP server

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, RFC2131 is clear on this:
If you - as sender of the DHCPDISCOVER - set the broadcastflag to true, the DHCPOFFER is sent to you as broadcast on L3 AND L2!!

RFC2131, chap 4.1:

- If this bit is set to 1, the DHCP message SHOULD be sent as an IP broadcast using an IP broadcast address (preferably 0xffffffff) as the IP destination address and the **link-layer broadcast** address as the link-layer destination address.
- If the BROADCAST bit is cleared to 0, the message SHOULD be sent as an IP unicast to the IP address specified in the 'yiaddr' field and the link-layer address specified in the 'chaddr' field.

Unfortunately, there are quite some DHCP server implementation that use IP broadcast and (wrongly) Ethernet unicast.